# TitleBar color in MFC application

Tags: visual-c++, mfc, windows-10, titlebar

I created the MFC app with the style: Visual Studio 2008. This style allows changing interface color in app. But this feature does not work for the title bar in Win10/11.  There I can change this color only in the system settings.  Therefore my question, is it possible to make it via MFC/Win32, any ideas
[image]

Comment: Probably have to override [`CWnd::OnNcPaint`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/cwnd-class?view=msvc-170#onncpaint), and render the whole thing yourself.

Comment: Additionally - the MFC feature pack was basically bought from BCGSoft. You can also buy their complete product and implement your own theme. See https://bcgsoft.com/support/DevArea/visualization_manager .